# How to declare different remove functions in RestAPI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Javascript and NodeJs.

I have two remove buttons in my html which should remove entries from a mongo database.

How do I divide the two delete or update operations to the Database? Is it possible to divide two delete functions for a Rest API?

Comment: As far as the API design is concerned, "you can do anything that makes the most sense to you."  You can define two (or more) API-requests which have the effect of "deleting something from a database."  (And, the fact that the interface is "RESTful" is actually beside the point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as per below:

```
app.delete('/api/MyApp/:my_json_key_1', controller.functionOne);
app.delete('/api/MyApp/:my_json_key_2', controller.functionTwo);
```